# how do i post radiogroup value(radiobutton text) using retrofit?

Tags: android, radio-button, retrofit, retrofit2, radio-group

i'm trying to post the radiogroup value(radiobutton text) by post request using retrofit....its not working though...following i tried the method

my layout where radiogroup is:-

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGrp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/confregpass"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/gendertext"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"

    >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioM"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:text="M"

      android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioF"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:text="F"
        android:buttonTint="#ffffff"

        />
</RadioGroup>
```

here is the method  for radiogroup:-**please help me in here**

```
      var gender = (findViewById<View>(R.id.radioGrp) as RadioGroup).clearCheck().toString()
      radioGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
          if (checkedId != -1) {
               gender = (findViewById<View>(checkedId) as RadioButton).text.toString()
          } else {
               gender = ""
          }
      })
```

here is my retrofit method:-youll see where im using gender-->

```
      RetrofitClient.instance.createUser(first_name, last_name, email, password, confirm_password,gender ,phone_no)
            .enqueue(object: Callback<DefaultResponse>{
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<DefaultResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<DefaultResponse>, response: Response<DefaultResponse>) {

                    var res = response
                    if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
                 .saveUser(response.body()?.data!!)

                      val intent = Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity::class.java)
                        intent.flags =
                          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            res.body()?.message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()

                        Log.d("kjsfgxhufb",response.body()?.status.toString())
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext, (response.body().toString())
                            ,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()

                        Log.d("edgerg", "" +  res.body()?.message)
                        Log.d("edgerg", "" +  response.message())


                    }
                }
            })
```

**Following is the output im getting in postman after posting/registering**

```
   ......
  "profile_pic": null,
    "country_id": null,
    "gender": "kotlin.Unit",
    "phone_no": "1234567890",
    .......
```

### What kotlin.Unit????

**i think im doing it wrong to get the radiobutton text value please help me...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have right now is surely that it is taking the default value which in this case is Kotlin.Unit, probably if you choose female manually, it will work for you.

The most correct way in my opinion is that you get the radiobutton selected when calling the createUser function and not a listener every time you touch an item.

```
 val selectedId: Int = radioGrp.checkedRadioButtonId
    var gender = if (selectedId != -1) {
        val selectedRadioButton =
            findViewById<RadioButton>(selectedId)
        selectedRadioButton.text.toString()
    } else {
        ""
    }
```